# p.stdout.read() empty when using python subprocess

Tags: python, shell

I try to get the output of a curl command by using the python subprocess. But the output is empty. Below is my source code:

```
def validateURL(url):
    p = subprocess.Popen("curl",
                         stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell = False)
    p.stdin.write("http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=" + url + "\n")
    p.stdin.close()
    stdout_data = p.stdout.read()
    print stdout_data
    result = re.findall("Error", stdout_data)
    print result # empty here
    if (len(result) != 0):
        return 'ERR'
    else:
        return 'OK'
```

Why? 
PS: I run this piece of code on my mac os and I use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `stderr = subprocess.PIPE,`, and see the error message printed by `curl`. Act accordingly to fix it.

One possible reason is that the URL should be specified as a command-line argument, and not on stdin:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(("curl", "http://..."), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the URL on the command line, so `curl` is printing an error message and exiting. Thus, there is no output on stdout. You're trying to send the URL on standard input, but `curl` does not work that way.

Instead, try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=" + url],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

Or, you know, just use `urllib2` (or `requests`) and do it in native Python instead of shelling out to `curl` and dealing with all that plumbing.

Answer (score 1):

You were passing data to `Popen` after it executed the command.
Try this:

```
def validateURL(url):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=" + url + "\n"],
                         stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell = False)
    stdout_data = p.stdout.read()
    print stdout_data
    result = re.findall("Error", stdout_data)
    print result # empty here
    if (len(result) != 0):
        return 'ERR'
    else:
        return 'OK'
```